# Understanding output shape of LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

1. With `print(rnn_forecast.shape) > (3172, 64, 1)`, why do we get the forecast in the shape of 64 at the 2nd dimension? Is this because we expected sequence to sequence by specifying return_sequence=True at the 2nd LSTM layer ?
2. In `final_result=rnn_forecast[split_time-window_size:-1, -1, 0]`, why we specify -1 at the 2nd dimension to get what we want as shown in prediction chart?

[The entire code in google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/192Qdh_JIPiuFvct8LkWuWI2OaJMnS8F_/view?usp=sharing)

```
# Define the training data set generator 
def windowed_dataset(series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer_size):
  series=tf.expand_dims(series, axis=-1)
  wd=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
  wd=wd.window(window_size+1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
  wd=wd.flat_map(lambda w : w.batch(window_size+1))
  wd=wd.shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)
  wd=wd.map(lambda w : (w[:-1],w[1:]))
  return wd.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)

window_size=64
batch_size=256
shuffle_buffer_size = 1000

train_series=windowed_dataset(train_series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer_size)
print(train_series.shape)
print(train_series)

> (3000,)
> <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, None, 1), (None, None, 1)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>

# Create the model and train it with train_series
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=1, padding="causal",activation="relu", input_shape=[None, 1]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : x*400))
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-5, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae'])
history=model.fit(train_series, epochs=100)

# Define prediction function
def model_forecast(model, series, window_size):
  series=tf.expand_dims(series, axis=-1) 
  series=tf.expand_dims(series, axis=-1) 
  wd=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
  wd=wd.window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
  wd=wd.flat_map(lambda w : w.batch(window_size))
  wd=wd.batch(32).prefetch(1)
  forecast=model.predict(wd)
  return forecast

# Prediction with series
rnn_forecast = model_forecast(model, series, window_size)
print(rnn_forecast.shape)
print(rnn_forecast)

> (3172, 64, 1)
> [[[ 95.66096  ]
    [112.35001  ]
    ...
    [ 19.893387 ]
    [ 21.324263 ]]
   ...
   [[101.16265  ]
    [124.68408  ]
    ...
    [ 11.329678 ]
    [ 7.8993587 ]]]

final_result=rnn_forecast[split_time-window_size:-1, -1, 0]
print(final_result)

> [135.31732   118.21495  ... 9.162828    11.344096]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plot_series(time_val, x_val)
plot_series(time_val, final_result)
```

Prediction chart

[image]

Comment: In my current understanding,
1. The forecast should be returned in the shape of 3 dimension, because we are specifying "return_sequence=True" at the 2nd LSTM layer. Besides, output shape was (None, None, 64) when I checked model.summary() . This means the model expects to output series, thus this is sequence to sequence model behavior.
2. As mentioned, we expect series to be output, so it is required to specify the last element to plot the prediction at the same period as time_val.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/AtrCheema/Miscellaneous_DL_Tutorials/blob/master/return_sequences_vs_return_states.ipynb) can help you!

Comment: Thank you for sharing. This is what i am assuming.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding of LSTM output shape

**Without return_sequences=True**

```
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
(32,4)
```

**With return_sequences=True**

```
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
(32,10,4)
```

When there are stacked LSTM layer in the model architecture it is expected to include `return_sequences=True`, since LSTM expects 3D input shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`.

Comment: I unerstood the idea of return_sequences. Thank you.